# Doctrine "matching" method on EXTRA_LAZY ManyToMany relation make invalid SQL request

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using Doctrine 3.1 with some `EXTRA_LAZY` associations.

**OneToMany** and **OneToOne** association work well but When I try an EXTRA_LAZY **ManyToMany** association, the `->matching($criteria)` methods has a strange behavior. The `Criteria::expr()->contains` create an invalid sql.

The following `AND te.name CONTAINS ?` is added to the Sql query.

Other associations (OneToOne and OneToMany) create a valid SQL with a `like % %`.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

After declaring a ManyToMany association in my class A :

```
#[ORM\JoinTable(name: 'association_A_B')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'A_id', referencedColumnName: 'A_id')]
#[ORM\InverseJoinColumn(name: 'B_id', referencedColumnName: 'B_id')]
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: B::class, fetch: "EXTRA_LAZY")]
private Collection $b;
```

This code :

```
$criteria = Criteria::create();
$criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->contains("name", "searchString"));
return $this->b->matching($criteria);
```

failed with this error :

> An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax
> error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'CONTAINS

To better understand the problem, I modified the Doctrine code to hard replace the `CONTAINS` by a `LIKE` :  it seems to work fine. I don't understand why Doctrine doesn't handle CONTAINS correctly in this case.